# Nodejs: response file to string not same as returning string

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

So when I attempt the following two responses from nodejs the behavior is different in the browser specifically chrome. I have a file with just the following content SOMESTRING

```
var string = fs.readSync(filename,'ascii');
res.end(string);
```

VS.

```
res.end('SOMESTRING');
```

and on the front end I use jQuery and I do the following.

```
$.ajax({type: params.type,
                    url: 'ajaxrequest',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {"name":"value"},
                    dataType:'text',
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            if(data == 'SOMESTRING')
                               console.log('data == SOMESTRING');
                    }
   });
```

No matter what the encoding is (utf8,etc) or trying string.toString() I can not get data == 'SOMESTRING' eventhough if I just res.end('SOMESTRING') the equality works just fine. And yes I am certain that there is no extra white spaces or return carriage.

Comment: What **is** the data delivered?

Comment: The payload response for data is SOMESTRING and typeof data is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `console.log('[' + data + ']');`. I'll bet you'll find a newline in there.